# Testing microdata in Gmail doesn't work

Tags: google-schemas

I've found some interesting pieces of code on Google Schemas and I know that the only way to test it without being whitelisted is sending mails to yourself, but my problem is that even that doesn't really work for me.

I've tried countless examples in both formats, but only the [Flight Reservation](https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/flight-reservation) and the [Go-To Action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action) are working at all... Even though I let everything run through Google's markup validator before testing and it turned out to be valid.
So... does anyone know if this is an error that lies with Google (missing functionality, wrong examples, faulty markup tester, ...) or am I in fact missing something which is the reason why it doesn't work?

(I'm sending/receiving the emails through the normal Gmail inbox in Firefox version 33.0. In case it's important, I'm using a Laptop with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS)

Comment: What specific thing are you trying to do that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality is still missing from Gmail. In other words, no one at Google working at Gmail has coded any functionality to pick up, for example cooking recipies.

Comment: So basically only the flight reservation and the Go To Action are currently working at all in Gmail, and everything else is more of a "coming soon" information (or it's being used by other applications)?